# Excel - SUMIFS always 00:00:00

Tags: excel, sumifs

I am trying to do something very simple that should work but doesn't; use a SUMIFS formula in Excel to return a HH:MM:SS date value except it always returns 00:00:00.

For example, column A is for month, B for names, C for time values.

```
=SUMIFS(C:C,A:A,"November",B:B,"Bob")
```

The result is always 00:00:00 when it should be something like 01:12:04. I've tried all sorts of cell formats, including creating a custom [hh]:mm:ss format but it makes no difference. I can't do something like:

```
=INDEX(C:C,MATCH("November",A:A,0)+MATCH("Bob",B:B)
```

Because the name column won't contain the same number of names each month. It does actually return a value though. What can I do, please?

Comment: Provide your excel file screenshot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you didn't offer your sheet I've created an example with given formula.

```
A (text)   B (text)  C (hh:mm)  D
October    Adam      02:01      =SUMIFS(C:C,A:A,"November",B:B,"Bob")
November   Bob       03:01      14:02
October    Bob       05:01      
November   Adam      07:01      
November   Bob       11:01
```

Your given formula works.

**Edit:** OP's solution: Edit time values as they're not recognized by pasting.

Comment: More or less. Each name only has one entry per month.

Comment: Of course this works without duplicates. Are your month values in column A text values?

Comment: Yes. Cell format is text value for month, full month name.

Comment: OK, your `SUMIFS` formula seems to be right. There must be something else. As bzimor sayd you should provide your sheet or an extract of it.

Comment: Resolved the problem, nothing to do with the formula. Because I had copied the time data into the sheet it is not... recognized correctly? Once you click on the cell, click on the formula bar and press enter, the formula can read the cell correctly.